# Using concept inside class

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I have a trait class that specifies base classes and derived classes for a class hierarchy. Some of the classes are templates, and I would like to have some `concepts` to help working with them.

Specifically, I have a template template argument `template<bool IsNode> typename GraphT`, and would like to have a concept that covers both `GraphT<true>` and `GraphT<false>`.

Is this possible?

Here is my attempt:

```cpp
template<template<bool> typename GraphT, typename Graph>
concept AnyBool = std::same_as<Graph, GraphT<true>> || std::same_as<Graph, GraphT<false>>;

template<template<bool> typename GraphT>
class GraphTypes {
public:
    template<bool IsNode> using Graph = GraphT<IsNode>;
    template<typename Graph> using AnyGraph = AnyBool<GraphT, Graph>;

    // Error: Concept cannot be nested inside class.    
    // template<typename Graph> concept AnyGraph = AnyBool<GraphT, Graph>;
};
```

You can try it out here: https://godbolt.org/z/nqoPqKKdr

Comment: I'm not seeing the purpose of the concept. Can you show how it's supposed to be used?